# Can L2 travel later time to join L1

Tags: visas, usa

I have a valid L1 Visa and my spouse has L2 visa. Both are valid for next three years. It's the first time we are going to the US.

I am travelling to the US next month, and my wife will travel in September. Is this alright? Had anyone experience with the situation like this?

*Expected Travel Dates are given in individual DS-160:* August First week
*My Travel*: End of August
*Spouse Travel*: End of September

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fine.  This possibility is explicit in the definition of the L visa category.  Like every other nonimmigrant visa category, it is defined in [8 USC 1101](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1101)(a)(15).  The relevant paragraph is 8 USC 1101(a)(15)(L):

> (L) subject to section 1184(c)(2) of this title, an alien who, within 3 years preceding the time of his application for admission into the United States, has been employed continuously for one year by a firm or corporation or other legal entity or an affiliate or subsidiary thereof and who seeks to enter the United States temporarily in order to continue to render his services to the same employer or a subsidiary or affiliate thereof in a capacity that is managerial, executive, or involves specialized knowledge, and the alien spouse and minor children of any such alien if accompanying him **or following to join him;**

(Emphasis added)

Comment: We gave expected travel date as August 8th for both in our individual DS-160 forms. But I am travelling on 25th of August and my spouse is travelling on September 25th. Can you please confirm this is also not a problem?

Comment: @Adapter it should be fine. They know that plans change, especially for a big international move like that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; you are free to travel separately. We have done that dozens of times.

The visa are given to the *persons*, and are valid for each person separately. You do not need to arrive together or even travel to the same places.

Her visa is a *dependant visa*; so if you do something that affects the visa basis (like getting a divorce), the situation might change, but if so, travelling together again has no effect on it.

Comment: `We have done that dozens of times` May I know whether your first-time entry was also separate or later entries to the US was separate?

Comment: They were separate, by a week or so. Nobody cared about it though.